# Can't access elements by Ajax event handler (using update panel)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

aspx looks like this:

```
            <asp:Panel ID="MedChangeScroll" CssClass="table-responsive scrollBlock" runat="server">
                <asp:Table ID="MedChangeTable" CssClass="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" runat="server"></asp:Table>
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:Button ID="EnableAddMedChangeBtn" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success" Text="Add Med Change" OnClick="enableAddMedChange" />
            <asp:Button ID="CancelAddMedChangeBtn" runat="server" Style="display: none;" CssClass="btn" Text="Cancel" OnClick="cancelAddMedChange" />
```

Everything is housed in an update panel. On the click of the EnableAddMedChangeBtn I run the following:

```
public void enableAddMedChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow();
            MedChangeTable.Rows.Add(tableRow);
            tableRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableBody;

            CancelAddMedChangeBtn.Style.Add("display", "inline-block");
            EnableAddMedChangeBtn.Style.Add("display", "none");
        }
}
```

In other words when the enableAddMedChangeBtn is clicked I add a row to the table and display the cancel button.

Now, when the cancel button is clicked, I cannot access the row that I added on the first click in the cancel button's event handler. In other words if the table had 2 rows and I added a 3rd, the table shows up as having two rows in the cancel button's event handler. In fact, if I comment out the entire cancel button event handler (but still let the empty method execute), the additional row gets deleted.

All help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Is ViewState enabled on the page and the table?

Comment: @Igor How do I check that?

Comment: does the page source in browser have __VIEWSTATE hidden input?

Comment: @Igor Yes, it does have viewstate in the source, I just don't know how to check if there is viewstate associated with the panel...

Comment: @Igor I just realized that there is an EnableViewState property on the update panel. I set it to true and still having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link: http://www.dotnetbull.com/2013/09/maintain-dynamic-control-events-data-during-postback.html.

It seems that dynamically created controls (i.e. controls which are not in the markup for the page) require a little additional plumbing to maintain.